# Make OSSEC ban ip on remote firewall

Tags: ids, iptables

I am deploying OSSEC architecture agent-server mode.
I want the server to ban ip not only on agent but also on a remote firewall (dedicated iptables server).

I've seached on the OSSEC's documentation but didn't find a way to do this so far ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by making a [customized active response](http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/ar/ar-custom.html). This will require you to write a script which can add IPs to your remote firewall. I suggest reading up on the linked documents as they explain this quite well.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i thought, no built-in solution, but there must be someone who allready did this. I'll try to find a script to share here .

Answer (score 4):

If you have an OSSEC agent running on the remote firewall, you can use native ossec commands.

The < location > option defines where the active response should be executed. Normally it is configured to execute the active response on the host that generated the event ("local"), but can also be configured to execute the active response on any host that has an agent ("defined-agent").

An example of an active response configuration that should always be executed on a specific host, no matter where it was triggered from (in this example the AR triggers on rules from the group ar_central_firewall and is executed on agent 123).

```
<active-response>
    <command>firewall-drop</command>
    <location>defined-agent</location>
    <agent_id>123</agent_id>
    <rules_group>ar_central_firewall</rules_group>
    <timeout>900</timeout>
</active-response>
```

The [OSSEC documentation](http://www.ossec.net/doc/syntax/head_ossec_config.active-response.html) has an overview of all possible configuration options for active responses.

Answer (score 1):

For peoples who are in the same case as me, here's a little script I wrote for the occasion:

```
remoteipdrop(){
    local client=$(cut -d':' -f1<<<"$1")
    local vuser=$(cut -d':' -f2<<<"$1")
        local vserver=$(cut -d':' -f3<<<"$1")
    cmd="ssh ${vuser}@${vserver} /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s ${client} -j DROP"
    $cmd
}

remoteipundrop(){
    local client=$(cut -d':' -f1<<<"$1")
    local vuser=$(cut -d':' -f2<<<"$1")
        local vserver=$(cut -d':' -f3<<<"$1")
    cmd="ssh ${vuser}@${vserver} /sbin/iptables -L INPUT -vn --line-number | \
        grep ${client} | cut -c 1 | xargs /sbin/iptables -D INPUT"
    $cmd
}

usage(){
    echo "Usage: $0 {drop} \"clientIP:serverIP:sshUser:sshServer\""
    echo "Exemples:"
    echo -e "\t$0 drop \"1.2.3.4:root:www.example.com\""
    echo -e "\t$0 open \"1.2.3.4:443:eth0:202.54.1.5:root:www03.example.com\""
    exit 1
}

line="$2"

[ $# -ne 2 ] && usage

case $1 in
    open) remoteipadd "$line";;
    close) remoteipdelete "$line";;
    drop) remoteipdrop "$line";;
    undrop) remoteipundrop "$line";;
    *) usage
esac
```

I'll add here how to link it whith active response.